# Breaking Up a Date Range by Individual Dates

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with the following features: Invoice ID, billing_period_start, billing_period_end, and items_purchased during that period.

I'm looking to break out a date range by individual dates. A date range can be contained within one month, but it can also be spread across two months, unequally. This will effectively create many more records than are currently in the table. Once I have done that, I need to breakout the amount of purchased items equally among that dates of the daterange.

```
billing_period_start      billing_period_end
--------------------      ------------------
2010-03-05                2010-03-07
2010-04-29                2010-05-05
2010-06-29                2006-08-12

billing_date
------------
2010-03-05  
2010-03-06
2010-03-07
2010-04-29
2010-04-30
2010-05-01
   ...
2010-05-05
2010-06-29
2010-06-30
   ...
2010-08-12
```

Now that the date range is broken into individual dates, I need to take the items_purchase and divide it by the number of the days in the billing period for each date, so that I have the items_purchase_per_date.

```
select
  invoice_line_id AS invoice_id
  ,items_purchased
  ,billing_period_start
  ,billing_period_end
  ,date_from_parts(YEAR(billing_period_start), MONTH(billing_period_start), 1) AS period1_month_start
  ,last_day(month_start, month) AS period1_month_end
  ,datediff(day, billing_period_start, billing_period_end) + 1 AS billing_period_length
from "INVOICE_DATA"
order by 1;
```

I'm running this on Snowflake, but can easily convert from mySQL, if someone knows that DBMS better.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your question is unclear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Just added more additional detail! Apologies! I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: @cmbramwell given sample data still does not make sense. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: I've read it twice and I still don't understand what exactly you try to achieve. Example input, output would be priceless here.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this in a data warehouse is using a [date dimension table](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/blog/b/community_blog/posts/why-use-a-date-dimension-table-in-a-data-warehouse). That is, a table that contains all the dates you need for analysis, plus any date attributes that are interesting as well, such as which week/month/quarter etc the date belongs to and so on.

Once you have table with unique rows for all relevant dates, you can more easily tackle date spine challenges like this.
For example, for your case you'd write (assuming `dates` is the name of your date dimension and `calendar_date` the name of the column containing the unique dates:

```
select
    d.calendar_date,
    i.*
from
    dates d
    join
    invoice_data i
        on d.calendar_date between i.billing_period_start and i.billing_period_end
```

Now you have one row per date between those start/end dates and you can do your daily billing allocation.